# How to pass possible class names to distilbert

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model

I've been trying to get distilbert to work and I've downloaded the model and used AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained() and AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(). I tried for a couple days now to pass the parameters from the "Possible class names" on the huggingface model card page: https://huggingface.co/typeform/distilbert-base-uncased-mnli?candidateLabels=positive%2C+negative%2C+neutral&multiClass=true&text=which+stocks+will+go+down+during+new+years

I tried:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSequenceClassification
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('.')
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('.')

text = "Dummy text"
text += "[SEP]Positive[SEP]Neutral[SEP]Negative"
encodedInput = tokenizer(text, return_tensors="pt")
output = model(**encodedInput)
print(output)
```

It's supposed to output entailment values for "Positive", "Neutral", and "Negative".
Anyone know how to do it? I'm using pytorch.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to append classes to the input text but you can define them in a separate list.

The `AutoModelForSequenceClassification` will generate the logits which when passed through `softmax` will give you the class label.

[One more suggestion: see the way I defined tokenizer & model. This way they can be downloaded on the way when you run the code.]

Please see the code below:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSequenceClassification
import torch

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('typeform/distilbert-base-uncased-mnli')
model     = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('typeform/distilbert-base-uncased-mnli')
classes   = ['positive', 'negative', 'neutral']
text      = "Dummy text"

encodedInput = tokenizer(text, return_tensors="pt")
output       = model(**encodedInput)
output       = torch.softmax(output[0], dim=1).tolist()[0]

max_idx = output.index(max(output))
print(classes[max_idx])
```